# How to create a CSV file using servlet?

Tags: java, servlets, csv

I want to download a CSV file from a *servlet*. I have data in the array of objects (`object[]`), I need to write it into CSV and download.

Could you help me how to do this in a servlet class?

Answer (score 11):

How can `Object[]` ever represent CSV data? Does it contain one row with several columns or several rows with one column? I'd imagine that `Object[][]` or `List<List<Object>>` makes more sense.

Anyway, when creating a CSV file you've to adhere the [RFC4180 spec](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180.txt). It's basically simple, there are only 3 strict rules:

1. Fields are separated by a comma.
2. If a comma occurs within a field, then the field has to be surrounded by double quotes.
3. If a double quote occurs within a field, then the field has to be surrounded by double quotes and the double quote within the field has to be escaped by another double quote.

Here's a kickoff example which does exactly that based on a `List<List<T>>` as source and an `OutputStream` as destination.

```
public static <T> void writeCsv (List<List<T>> csv, char separator, OutputStream output) throws IOException {
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(output, "UTF-8"));
    for (List<T> row : csv) {
        for (Iterator<T> iter = row.iterator(); iter.hasNext();) {
            String field = String.valueOf(iter.next()).replace("\"", "\"\"");
            if (field.indexOf(separator) > -1 || field.indexOf('"') > -1) {
                field = '"' + field + '"';
            }
            writer.append(field);
            if (iter.hasNext()) {
                writer.append(separator);
            }
        }
        writer.newLine();
    }
    writer.flush();
}
```

Here's how you can use it in a Servlet:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    List<List<Object>> csv = getItSomehow();
    response.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/csv");
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\"file.csv\"");
    writeCsv(csv, ';', response.getOutputStream());
}
```

*(note that Europe based locales use a semicolon instead of comma for CSV files, feel free to change)*

The `Content-Disposition` of `attachment` will force a *Save As* dialogue. Note that MSIE has the misbehaviour that it doesn't take the `filename` as default filename in the *Save As* dialogue, but it instead takes the last part of the pathinfo. So if this servlet is for example invoked by http://example.com/csv, then you'll get `csv` as default filename. Rather append it to the pathinfo like follows http://example.com/csv/file.csv. The servlet should only be mapped on an `url-pattern` of `/csv/*` instead of `/csv`.

Comment: that could be written as `public static void writeCsv (List<? extends List<?>> csv, char separator, OutputStream output)` and change all the `T` to `?`

Answer (score 1):

Here's an attempt:

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
                HttpServletResponse response)
  throws ServletException, IOException {

    // Other stuff you know that I don't..

    Object[] data = search.getSearch();
    response.setContentType("text/csv");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    for (Object d : data) {
        out.println(d.field1 + "," + d.field2 + "," + d.field3 + ...);
    }
}
```

This broken if your fields have commas for data.  I leave you to figure out how to do that since it's a quick [Google Search](http://www.google.com/search?q=csv+escaping).

Answer (score 1):

There is the [JavaCSV](http://sourceforge.net/projects/javacsv/) which will help you generate the csv representation.

Then you can write the file using:

- `response.getWriter()` to print the contents
- `response.setContentType("text/csv")`

Answer (score 0):

Here's some (redacted for brevity and generality) code from a production servlet I have running. It should be trivial to swap in your specific data array with the code below.

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

        res.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
        res.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"TSR.csv\"");
        try {
            // Write the header line
            OutputStream o = res.getOutputStream();
            String header = "ID,ControlNumber\n";
            o.write(header.getBytes());

            // Write the data lines
            Vector records = getRecords(); // Custom to my app
            Iterator i = records.iterator();
            while (i.hasNext()) {
                                // Custom data object; use your own
                StandardReportDTO sr = (StandardReportDTO) i.next();
                StringBuffer line = new StringBuffer();
                line.append(sr.getID());
                line.append(",");
                line.append(sr.getControlNumber());
                line.append("\n");
                o.write(line.toString().getBytes());
                o.flush();
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
//          log.error(e);
        }
}
```