# Java Escaping String for Storage in csv file

Tags: java, csv, escaping

If want to store user created strings in a csv file.
Is there a preferred library to use for Escaping the string or should I write my own function?

Comment: possible duplicate of [csv api for java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/101100/csv-api-for-java)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/200609/can-you-recommend-a-java-library-for-reading-and-possibly-writing-csv-files

Comment: Look here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSV_application_support

Comment: RFC 4130 is pretty simple though. Here's another example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3190303/how-to-create-csv-file-using-servlet/3190598#3190598

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest you use one of the libraries recommended by the post(s) here. While it may seem easy to write your own CSV creator/parser, you are going to run into issues where you need to handle scenarios such as user strings with commas or quotes in them, which can sometimes be quite cumbersome. I used the following libraries and they worked fine:-

- [com.Ostermiller.util Java Utilities](http://ostermiller.org/utils/CSV.html)
- [opencsv](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: opencsv - Nice, lean JAR library that worked great for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 19):

For anyone looking for code:
add this to your pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
</dependency>
```

Then use:

```
 String escaped = StringEscapeUtils.escapeCsv("tHIS String 'needs escaping'");
 System.out.println(escaped); //safe for csv
```

**UPD:** as of version 3.6, `StringEscapeUtils` in `commons-lang` deprecated, so you have to use `commons-text` instead:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-text</artifactId>
    <version>1.6</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Could you add the reference which says `commons-lang` is deprecated? I see it's still being updated: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3

Comment: Had to clone `org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils.CsvEscaper` as it doesn't support semicolon-delimeted CSV.

Answer (score 4):

I ended up using [StringEscapeUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html), mostly because I already had the dependency in my project. Works like a charm!
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

If you are writing your own implementation , then here is RFC for you reference:
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180

If your string are not too complicated you can easily develop small function rather than using some library. I have referenced above RFC and created small function for same purpose in one of my projects.