# HttpServletResponse to javax.ws.rs.core.Response

Tags: java, rest, http

I have a Rest Get api:

```
@GET
@Path("myEndpoint")
public Response getSomething(@Context HttpServletResponse response) {
  // do something with httpServletResponse

}
```

How do I return the updated `HttpServletResponse` as `javax.ws.rs.core.Response`?

Comment: Just by pasting the Title of that Q in google you will find a lot of info and why @BackSlash answer covers the question...

Comment: shouldn't the GET method take `HttpServletRequest` instead of `...Response` ?

Comment: @Ruslan there are some cases where you would like to capture the response there. Like for instance reset the responce, override with your custom Content type (headers/body) manually and return it again. Let's say like old school way of a "report file" download. [Check this out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21378773/create-and-download-csv-file-javaservlet). Request is not used in the accepted answer and could be omitted.

Comment: Did my answer help or did I misunderstand your question?

Comment: @user7294900: I think my question was not clear. I wanted to add some cookies in my Response. But not NewCookie cookies, but http Cookies. So after grabbing HttpServletResponse and adding cookies into it, how do I return that response? That was the doubt. I solved it differently though.. as in with NewCookie. So nevermind! thanks for the response though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update `HttpServletRequest` by adding it with `@Context` in class

```
@Context
private HttpServletRequest request;
```

And check it in method

```
 // do something with httpServletResponse
 checkRequest(request);
```

Answer (score 0):

Expanding a bit on @BlackSlash answer,
a better syntax would be:

```
Response.status(Response.Status.OK).entity(any object here).build();
Or another example:
Response.status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST).entity("Error message...").build();
```

Just remember to set the media type correctly for example:

```
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
```