# Create and download TXT file in a Java servlet

Tags: javascript, java, ajax

I found [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21378773/create-and-download-csv-file-ina-java-servlet) of Gourav.
If I call the servlet from the browser it works but if I use a            "POST" call with AJAX, it only recovers the text but does not automatically download the file..

Can anyone explain how I can do this?
Thank you!

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
     response.setContentType("text/plain");
     response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"myTxtFile.txt\"");

     StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
     sb.append("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur elit.");
     sb.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
     sb.append("parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.");
     sb.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
     sb.append("Duis magna neque, malesuada non condimentum posuere.");

     OutputStream outputStream = response.getOutputStream();

     String outputResult = sb.toString();
     outputStream.write(outputResult.getBytes());
     outputStream.flush();
     outputStream.close();
```

}

Comment: It's not possible to download a file (that is write it to disk) with AJAX/JavaScript. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4545311/download-a-file-by-jquery-ajax